# "Command 'soruce' not found" when trying to execute bashrc (not a typo)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

When I try any of the following I always get the above error

`sudo bash`

`source ~/.bashrc`

`sudo -s`

Even if I'm explicitly using the 'source' command it seems to think I'm typing in 'soruce' instead. Could this be an issue with some of the source bash code? Like for some reason the 'source' is spelled incorrectly somewhere somehow?

Comment: misspelled in the title too :p

Comment: As, It was just a typo problem, This post is not much more helpful for others. Would advise to delete your post. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

So yes, the answer was the a 'source' command was spelled wrong at the bottom of ~/.bashrc file. I changed it from soruce to source and it seems to be working now